# Dynamically created DOM element in the loop gets overwritten and lose the track of current data value

Tags: javascript, html, loops, model-view-controller

Sorry if the title is not clear but I'm still a newbie and often don't know how to clearly communicate my programming problem and question. Anyways.

I'm making a quiz app. Quiz app has a controller object which has a method for question incrementation and if the answer is correct - the current score incrementation. Then I have another function which is populating the screen with the questions and answer options. The questions and answers are in array so I create ul, li elements and loop through them inside the loop to populate the newly created DOM elements with question values.

Now the problem is that if I create LI elements for answer choices dynamically inside the loop, the quiz score stays at 0 no matter if I answer correctly or not. If I create LI element outside the loop and then inside the loop populate its innerHTML value, I can keep track of current score, but it's only one LI element created, so if I have 2 or more answer choices, only one is being displayed inside that LI element. Some code:

```
function Quiz(questions) {
  this.questions = questions
  this.score = 0;
  this.questionIndex = 0;
}

Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
  return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}

Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {

  if (this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {

    this.score++;
  }
    this.questionIndex++;
}

function Question(theQuestion, theChoices, theCorrectAnswer) {
  this.theQuestion = theQuestion;
  this.theChoices = theChoices;
  this.theCorrectAnswer = theCorrectAnswer;
}

Question.prototype.isCorrectAnswer = function(choice) {
    return this.theCorrectAnswer === choice;
}

let thequestion = [
  new Question("Which one of the three is a programming language?", ["Javascript", "HTML", "CSS"], "Javascript"),
  new Question("Is NodeJS is a front end or back end framework?", ["Back end", "Front End"], "Back end"),
  new Question("Is JAVA object oriented language?", ["Yes", "No"], "Yes")
]

var quiz = new Quiz(thequestion);


function populate() {

  if (quiz.isEnded()) {
    console.log("finished");
    showScores();
  } else {
    var questionTextField = document.getElementById("questions");
    questionTextField.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().theQuestion;

    var choicesField = document.getElementById("options");
    var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().theChoices;

    var ul = document.createElement("UL");
    choicesField.appendChild(ul);
    for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
      var li = document.createElement("LI");
      ul.appendChild(li);
      li.innerHTML = choices[i];
      guess(choices[i]);
    }

    ul.addEventListener("click", function() {
      choicesField.removeChild(ul);
    })
    console.log(quiz.score);
  }
}

function guess(guess) {
  var optionsToClick = document.getElementById("options");
  optionsToClick.onclick = function(e) {
    quiz.guess(guess);
    populate();
  }
}
```

Like I said, using this code I get all answer options out on the screen from array in the individual LI elements, but when I click the correct answer the score is not incremented. I believe that's because on each loop iteration the LI is overwritten so the score is always at 0, right?

If I create LI element outside the loop:

```
var ul = document.createElement("UL");
        choicesField.appendChild(ul);
var li = document.createElement("LI");
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
          ul.appendChild(li);
          li.innerHTML = choices[i];
          guess(choices[i]);
        }
```

The score gets incremented when I click the correct answer, but out of 3 or more answer choices I get only one (the last one from array) out on the screen because there is only one LI element created outside the loop and inside the loop it gets overwritten on each iteration with new question answer choices.

So how can I solve this problem? I want to dynamically create the same amount of answer buttons as there is for each question answer choices and keep track of the current score on each button click and new loop iteration without reseting the score to 0. Is this the problem with the closures?

The solution I was thinking about was to follow observer pattern and notify the observer (newly created LI elements inside the loop) with the current score value (I could keep them in array) and update the current LI with those values by setting data attribute on them? So it would work like comparing old score value in array with the new one and updating newly created LI elements in the loop on each iteration. That way they could keep the track of the score.

I don't know if that makes sense and if I'm not overthinking it. Hope I can get some advice to get me on the track the right direction.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It1XJ.png)

[image]